# FirewallDが動作しない(org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDeniedエラー)

Tags: centos

ServersMan@VPS(DTI)のCentOS7のVPS上で、ファイアウォールを設定するためFirewallDの使い方を調べ、見つけたサイトのとおりに設定しました。

ところが、設定完了後にFirewallDをstartしても、`$ sudo systemctl status firewalld` の表示は `Active: inactive(dead)` のままで、その下に赤い文字で

```
   2015-03-01 15:07:27 ERROR: Exception DBusException: 
   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.71" is not 
   allowed to own the service "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" due to 
   security policies in the configuration file
```

と表示されています。

どうすれば正常にFirewallDを起動できるのでしょうか?

打ったコマンドは以下のとおりです。

```
$ yum -y install firewalld firewalld-service firewalld-config 
$ sudo systemctl start firewalld
$ sudo systemctl enable firewalld
$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

Comment: `systemctl enable` したときに `ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/...` といったメッセージは表示されているでしょうか。 start/enable/status を実行した際の出力を記載してもらえますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お使いの VPS はコンテナ型なのではないでしょうか。コンテナ型だと kernel は仮想化ホスト側と共通なので、kernel の機能は使えません。
dbus, firewalld だけでなく、iptables 自体も使えないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 調べてみたらServersMan@VPSはOpenVZを使用していて、仰る通りKernelをホストと共有しているようです。ありがとうございました。